# How can I track my current campaigns in dashboard at Home Page

Tags: dashboard, campaign, home-page-component

I have created a dashboard on my salesforce homepage but I don't know how to track my current campaigns in dashboard?
Can anybody help?

Comment: is that my answer solves your issue?

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you have created dashboard which has a component which refers to Campaign report. If not, then refer [Create a New Dashboard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_analytics.meta/workbook_analytics/analytics1_step1.htm).

Post creation, go to Home page:

In the Home Page, Dashboard section click on `Customize Page` link which will navigate to `Customize your Home Page`. There you can select Dashboard Snapshot from the drop down list and press `Save`. The selected dashboard will be displayed (first row of the dashboard, max 3 components) in the Home page.

See the picture below.

[image: Customize Dashboard]